# A subbundle of a direct sum of vector bundles

Tags: vector-bundles, direct-sum

Suppose that $N$ be a vector subbundle of $M_1 \oplus M_2 \oplus ... \oplus M_k$ where $M_1, M_2, ..., M_k$ are line bundles on a smooth algebraic curve $X$. Let $N_i$ be the image of $N$ under the projection $M_1 \oplus M_2 \oplus ... \oplus M_k \to M_i$. Is it true that $N=N_1 \oplus N_2 \oplus ... \oplus N_k$?

Comment: I don't think that's even true for vector spaces.

Comment: Think about the line $x_1=x_2$ in $\Bbb R\oplus\Bbb R$. This is just the vector space case of the answer Spenser gave. Start simple!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Take $M_1=M_2=X\times\mathbb{C}$ and $N=\{(x,u,v)\in M_1\oplus M_2=X\times\mathbb{C}^2:u=v\}$. Then, $N_1=M_1$ and $N_2=M_2$ so $N\neq N_1\oplus N_2$.

Comment: Thank you very much! Do you think you could give an example when $M_1$ and $M_2$ are non-isomorphic line bundles?